# ng-change not firing for each ng-model initialization

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-ng-change

My understanding of how ng-change and ng-model 'work together' is that, say for an array which has N elements, if I use ng-repeat over this collection in a view binding the current index to the ng-model, and then bind an ng-change function to each element, then on initialization of the view, **the ng-change function will fire at least N times**. Turns out I am wrong, here to get some insight into why.

Some code to explain further:

```
 $scope.quiz = {

      sections: [
          {
              questions: [
                   {
                       value: 0,
                       title: "Question 1"
                   }
              ]
          },
          {
              questions: [
                   {
                       value: 0,
                       title: "Question 1"
                   },
                   {
                       value: 0,
                       title: "Question 2"
                   }
              ]
          }
      ]
 };
```

I have a dataset somewhat similar to what I have posted above, in my view I am using an ng-repeat to generate input elements for each question inside each section; something along the lines of:

```
<!-- Loop through each section -->
<div ng-repeat="section in quiz.sections">

    <!-- Loop through each question -->
    <input type="number" ng-repeat="question in section.questions" ng-model="question.value" ng-change="change()"/>

</div>
```

My ng-change function is fairly intensive and there is no need to execute this intensive code when the page is loading, the code doing the donkey work only needs firing when the user interacts with the view.

So I define a counter to keep track of how many times the ng-change has been fired, when it has hit it's MAX value (which is the number of questions in my data structure) I assume that the page has finished initializing and then inside my ng-change function I define a new function and set the ng-change function to reference that, thus the code dealing with user interaction is not run on initialization.

Along the lines of the below:

```
 var count = 0; //Keep track of how many times change has been fired
 var MAX = quiz.getQuestionCount(); //How many questions in the quiz 

 $scope.change = function() {

      /*
            Do nothing for now
      */


      /*
       * Once this has been fired MAX times, assign the 'actual logic'
       * to the change function.
       *
       * MAX is not being reached...
      */
      if(count >= MAX) {

          $scope.change = function() {
               /*
                  Some intensive computation that doesn't need 
                  to be invoked during the 'initial load' of the page
                  ...
                  ...
               */
          };
      }

 };
```

The issue is that count < MAX once the page has loaded, I originally thought that the ng-change would get fired every time the ng-repeat iterated over the dataset it's given during the compilation process of the view, the example above tells me i'm wrong.

Naturally if I do something illogical like:

```
   if(count >= MAX / 2) {
        //This gets triggered
   }
```

But naturally I am not going to rely on 'magic' :).

Question:

If I have an array of 30 elements and ng-repeat over them assigning a ng-model and ng-change value, i'd expect the ng-change to get fired at least 30 times when the page (namely the controller) is loaded, this does not appear to be true, can anyone explain why?

My understanding is that initializing a ng-model value should trigger the change event, this can't be true if the ng-change is executed less than 30 times when the page is loaded in the above example.

Comment: Many thanks as a last line should not be removed IMO - When posting a long question such as this, I think it's only right to give 'Many thanks' to those who read through all that text! - Cheers for the rapid edit though lol.

Comment: what is your actual question? you took the time to make a comment thanking people for reading through the text, but there is no actual question in the question body; instead you have listed a theory you have about something and told us your theory is incorrect.

Comment: aside from that, your entire question body discusses how you expect `ng-change` to work, but you didn't list any HTML that has `ng-change`.

Comment: on top of all that, your understanding of `ng-change` seems flawed.  `ng-change` monitors the *value* of an input for changes, not the *rendering* of an input, and if `ng-repeat` is changing the values of your properties, you have other more major issues than `ng-change`.

Comment: @Claies ng-repeat does not change the input at all. Added the ng-change directive to the html snippet.

Comment: `ng-model` doesn't "initialize" a value, it merely assigns a reference to a property name.  If the text box is still empty when you attempt to access the property, that property's value will be `undefined`.

Comment: also, according to the documentation for `ng-change`, https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange#!/ "The ngChange expression is only evaluated when a change in the input value causes a new value to be committed to the model.

It will not be evaluated:
•if the model is changed programmatically and not by a change to the input value"